# Reduce logging of the same exceptioins

Tags: java, swing, logging

Are there any smart ways to reduce logging of "equals" exceptions?

For example:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong parameter, should be a float from 0 to 100
at com.test.Foo.setAmount(Foo.java:93)
at com.test.Bar.setAmounts(Bar.java:39)
at com.test.Bar2.init(Bar2.java:152)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
```

such exception can be thrown 90 times per second under specific circumstances. We use AWT handler to log exceptions, and it can "freeze" all Swing's application.

The first workaround which came to mind was to log exceptions in a different thread, but such approch may be a real hell in later debug.

The second thought was to put exceptions in a WeakHashMap and log exception only for first occurance. Im not sure how to perform equals for exception and whether it will be fast enough at all.

Comment: paste your code where it throws exception.

Comment: does this can help? exception throws from 3rd party lib and I do obtain it from proxy listeners and log it

Comment: when you get exception you should not log exception object as a whole. if you get message populated then you should use exception.getMessage(). It depends on your third part lib whether thye populate it or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), there is a Filter called [DuplicateMessageFilter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#DuplicateMessageFilter) that drops messages after a certain repetition.

Answer (score 2):

What if you write an ExceptionWrapper class and implement equals() method which compare message and stack trace. Then logger keeps LinkedHashSet of the wrappers where newly happened exceptions are added. The logger logs the Set e.g. each second (or any different time interval). Thus newly added "equal" exceptions replace older.