# Can I make Log4J suppress logging specific messages for a time?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I thought this is a pretty basic requirement, although difficult to implement efficiently:

At one codebase, we log quite a bit, depending on user behavior. For the sake of argument say every click on a button creates a log message with the name of the clicked button.

Now, I don't care about each and every clicked button. I'm quite content having one message printed once every 5 minutes, regardless of the number of times the user clicked the button.

I can do this pretty easily in user code:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("buttons");
private static final long LOG_ONLY_EVERY = Duration.ofMinutes( 5 ).getSeconds();

private static final Map<String, Long> loggedViolations = new HashMap<>();

public static void logClick( String buttonName )
{
    String msg = "Button " + buttonName + " has been clicked";

    final long epochSecond = Instant.now( Clock.systemUTC() ).getEpochSecond();
    if ( !loggedViolations.containsKey( msg ) )
    {
        loggedViolations.put( msg, epochSecond );
    }
    if ( loggedViolations.get( msg ) + LOG_ONLY_EVERY < epochSecond )
    {
        LOG.warn( msg );
        loggedViolations.put( msg, epochSecond );
    }
}
```

My **question** is: can SLF4J or Log4J do this for me? How?

And yes, I'm aware the above code is lacking synchronization. If the answer to the above question is "no, do it yourself" - would the above be safe in a multi-threaded environment (since I don't remove messages, anyway)?

Comment: If you ever do it yourself, MDC may help you a little. See this link for logback (which works with slf4j), and I think log4j has the same system : http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Comment: @Berger Can you explain how MDC would help me here? I'm only interested in knowing a particular event occurred at all, I'm not after who caused it nor with which frequency. That's the reason I assumed a `HashMap` would be safe even with multiple writers.

Comment: MDC acts like a HashMap but linked to the current (calling) Thread, I thought it could be a replacement for your own custom HashMap . If you are dealing with multiple Threads, yes maybe this isn't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [BurstFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html) and install it on the `buttons` logger:

> The BurstFilter provides a mechanism to control the rate at which LogEvents are processed by silently discarding events after the maximum limit has been reached.

For Logback use the [DuplicateMessageFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758072/reduce-logging-of-the-same-exceptioins).

Comment: So to clarify - to allow one message each 5 minutes, the `rate` would be `1/3000` and `maxBurst = 1`? Otherwise, great find!

Comment: @mabi  That looks right.  Best to always write a unit test to confirm that it works as expected.